# Simple client query tool question

Tags: postgresql

Hope everyone is having a good week. I have what I believe to be a simple straightforward question about Postgres editors.

I have worked with 3 relational databases over the last 5 years (Teradata, MySQL & MSSQL), but encountered Postgres in the last month.

I'm an analyst, so my day to day is a lot of ad hoc querying.

In the past I have been used to the idea of simple luxuries: tabs in query editors, a quick CMD-S to save, etc.

My question is - why do these features lack in so many Postgres editors?

Postico for example has no easy save option - who does not save queries they write?

Is the way Postgres typically is used fundamentally different than other databases? I understand some are optimized for high throughput etc, but is my use (analyst) so very different than features developers would need?

Is it just because I'm relying on open source editors? 
Anyone have recommendations?

Thanks
-Justin

Comment: Hi, do you need to know some PG client tools ? How about pgAdmin, this is a good tool which I'm using.

Comment: Did you check this list? http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - why do these features lack in so many Postgres editors?

What are you missing? You can do it all with psql[1] or PGAdmin III[2].

Take a look[3][4] how to customize psql to interact with our editor/environment.

> Postico for example has no easy save option - who does not save queries they write?

That's a good question. :P

> Is the way Postgres typically is used fundamentally different than other databases? I understand some are optimized for high throughput etc, but is my use (analyst) so very different than features developers would need?

IMHO the PostgreSQL community share a ideia of make a simple tool for each job. You can do all the job, but using each of this 'tiny' tools.

Database vendors, like Microsoft and Oracle, always make a super tool with all options and probably call this small tools to help.

MSSQL it's a great database but, without the Management Studio, it's hard to work with.

> Is it just because I'm relying on open source editors? Anyone have recommendations?

There's a few comercial options, like @Lauri already suggested, take a look at the wiki[5][6] for more options.

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html
2. https://www.pgadmin.org/
3. http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/02/21/more-out-of-psql/
4. http://akorotkov.github.io/blog/2016/06/09/psql-graph/
5. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools
6. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools